# How to hide bottom bar in Android Tablet emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I'm developing Android application in Android Studio and use Android Virtual Device Manager (AVD Manager) for debugging.

Now, I want to publish my app to the PlayMarket and I need to upload screenshots of me application for mobile device and tablets 7" and 10".

I run AVD `Nexus 10` with `Android API 33` and get screenshots like this.

[image]

How can I get rid of the bottom bar? I don't want these icons on the my app screenshots in PlayMarket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a new feature for Android 12L (L = "Large) called the "taskbar". Read about it [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/12L/summary). If you don't want it in your screenshots, just use an emulator with a lower API level.

Answer (score 12):

If you remove all icons from the taskbar (e.g. move them onto desktop), the taskbar will disappear.

Comment: Thanks, (don't like this bottom bar)

Comment: I still had the suggested icons, to hide them you have to: "Settings" => "Apps" => "Default apps" => "Home app" (settings icon) => "Suggestions" => disable "Suggestions on Home screen"

Comment: Another problem I encountered is saving the emulator state upon shutdown. In order not to lose the change when closing the emulator I had to: "Android Studio" => "Virtual Device Manager" => "device_name" (pencil icon) => "Show Advanced Settings" => enable "Cold boot"