# System bar showing app icons on Android 13 (tablet emulator)

Tags: android, tablet

From Android 13 (API 33) the the system bar in the bottom is showing a row of app icons when using different apps. On the home screen it is not visible, but when you open up an app or navigates into the system settings you will see it in the bottom.

See attached screenshot for details.

I cannot find a way to disable it through the system settings, and I also haven't found a way to programmatically disable it in the app I'm developing.

Do you know a way to disable it, or at least control the visibility on it? Maybe it is just an emulator issue?

[image: Android settings view with app icons in system bar]

Comment: have you tried using flags View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    |View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    |View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY

Answer (score 1):

Looks to have been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72755571/how-to-hide-bottom-bar-in-android-tablet-emulator) previously. Answers there suggested either:

- Dragging and moving all of the apps from the taskbar onto the home screen, and when you open any app, the taskbar will collapse.

  - This worked for me and allowed me to use the later API versions
- Using an emulator with a lower API version than Android 12L which added the taskbar.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).